# Drawing a set of elliptical shape partitions using tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, decorations

I would like to draw a region of elliptical shape with 3 partitions. Each partition should be shaded and labeled differently (e.g., green, yellow and orange partition).

Comment: Could you add either a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) showing what you've attempted so far or at least a sketch showing what you want to draw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Here's what I think you may mean, let me know if it isn't.
It works because an ellipse is just a stretched circle and circle and arcs are (relatively) easy to draw in tikz (as opposed to an ellipse where you would probably have to work with the equations directly).

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=20]{standalone}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{scope}[xscale=2]
            \draw (0, 0) circle[radius = 3cm];
            \coordinate (A) at (60:3);
            \coordinate (B) at (-60:3);
            \coordinate (C) at (120:3);
            \coordinate (D) at (-120:3);
            \fill[green, opacity=0.3] (A) arc(60:-60:3);
            \fill[orange, opacity=0.3] (C) arc(120:240:3);
            \fill[yellow, opacity=0.3] (A) arc(60:120:3) -- (D) arc(-120:-60:3) -- cycle;
            \node[green] at (2, 0) {Green};
            \node[orange] at (-2, 0) {Orange};
            \node[yellow] at (0, 0) {Yellow};
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

Three equal nodes inside a clipped path:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    onethird/.style={minimum width=2cm, minimum height=3cm, fill=#1!30, text=#1!30!black, outer sep=0pt}
]
\path[clip] circle (3cm and 1.5cm);
\node[onethird=red](R){Red};
\node[onethird=green, left=0pt of R](G){Green};
\node[onethird=blue, right=0pt of R](B){Blue};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]